# How can I connect my splunk using Splunk SDK Java?

Tags: java, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-sdk

I am getting Getting URI can't be null when trying with the url

Below is my code,

```
HttpService.setSslSecurityProtocol(SSLSecurityProtocol.SSLv3);
 //Tried the below one also
 //HttpService.setSslSecurityProtocol(SSLSecurityProtocol.TLSv1_2);

      ServiceArgs loginArgs  = new ServiceArgs();
      loginArgs.setUsername("username");
      loginArgs.setPassword("password");
      loginArgs.setHost("my splunk url"); //for eg http://splunkdet.mysite.com:8000/login
      loginArgs.setPort(8000);

      Service service = Service.connect(loginArgs);

      for (Application app: service.getApplications().values()) {
       System.out.println(app.getName());
      }
```

Getting Exception "**URI can't be null**" `Service service = Service.connect(loginArgs);`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The host should probably be just a host, not an HTTP endpoint. Especially since you are setting the port on the following line

Comment: Did you try to see examples at https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-java/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Since your using http and not https you don't need to use HttpService.setSslSecurityProtocol.

Instead add the scheme to your ServiceArgs
example : loginArgs.setScheme("http");

And don't include http:// or https:// in the URL you pass to setHost.